# How to find correct IP address of WSL/Linux to be used in WinSCP?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, winscp, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to transfer files from Windows to Linux through WinSCP. The problem is I cannot find the correct IP address of the Linux ssh server to be used in the WinSCP.

I am using Ubuntu-20.04 Linux in WSL.

I have tried the IP addresses returned by the following commands, but none has worked!

`sudo apt install net-tools` followed by `ifconfig` gives: `172.xx.xx8.1`

`cat /etc/resolv.conf` gives: `172.xx.xx0.234`

`curl https://ipinfo.io/ip ; echo` gives: `207.xxx.xx.130`

... and on and on. I have tried all these, but none worked.

I thought this is due to the wrong port number, but I checked and it was 22.  Then I activated an ssh and firewall, but still no success.

I can easily open the WSL directory and drag files there, but I'd like to use WinSCP.  How can I connect to WSL using WinSCP?

Comment: 172.16.* is used for local communications within a private network. 207.* is your external ip (which you do not need in this case). https://data-flair.training/blogs/transfer-data-from-windows-to-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for reposting it over here (and replying on SO with the heads-up that you'd reposted)  Just for clarity, the Windows host under which you are using is the same that has WSL installed, right?  You aren't trying to access WSL from a *different* Windows system on the network, right?

Comment: This is what I have done so far. I have installed the Ubuntu-20.04 using wsl command through powershell. have setup some requirements in the Linux; now I am trying to transfer files through the WinSCP to the Linux system. Using the same windows that I installed the linux with its wsl. Tried this https://data-flair.training/blogs/transfer-data-from-windows-to-ubuntu/ and it did not work.

Comment: @M.Arablu I'm assuming this is WSL2, but can you confirm it with a `wsl -l -v` (from PowerShell or CMD)?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by *"activated an ssh"*?

Comment: After doing the WSL version check that @NotTheDr01ds suggested, please update your tags to reflect the WSL version.  It will help many people in the future.  WSL1 (my fav) and WSL2 are two different beasts.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds the result of (wsl -l -v) through PowerShell is (  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2)